# unable to read from input stream socket in java

Tags: java, sockets, arraylist, jackson, inputstream

im writing a client/server application which are communicating over a tcp socket .
and im facing a problem now in final stages of my work . the problem is i have a `arrayList<object>` on the server and im trying to serialize it using `jackson` and send it to the client . it works perfectly when the array has only one object in it . but when there is two objects or more in my `arrayList` the server will correctly send it to the client but on the client side it looks like im not receiving anything it will still stuck on `read()` part like nothing is receiving .

im also flushing the output stream . and the serialization is correct i can see .

i have to mention that im sending and receiving all other things perfectly but i only have problem with `ArrayLists` which includes more than one Object in them .

here is how im sending the data : ( it throws no error and it sending it tottaly correct ):

```
write(Repository.clone(mainServer.findSpecifidUsername(repository.getSelf().getLoginForm().getUsername()), repository));
```

here is the write function :

```
public boolean write (String string)
    {
        try
        {
            this.streamOut.writeUTF(string);
            streamOut.flush();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and here is how im reading it on my client side :

```
String json = User.communicationConnection.read();
```

and here is the read function :

```
public String read()
    {
        String string;
        try
        {
            string = this.streamIn.readUTF();
            return string;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Please provide serialized strings where there is one object in array and couple objects in array. What function do you use for sending data?

Comment: And what kind of stream do you use for reading / writing?

Comment: thank you guys i it was because the length of the string was very very huge .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the problem somehow . it was because i was sending a really large String ( more than 4000 characters ) even for when there was one object in the array ( it was not my fault the object had alot of fields ;-) ) and when i was serializing the array included more than one objects it would have become a really really large String which would take it forever to be received on the other end . 
the solution is whether to send it in bytes or just sending smaller strings .

i did the second solution and its fine now .